# Is Elixir's module an atom?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm trying to get to know what modules are in Elixir. Because in Erlang they're just atoms, but in Elixir atoms start with `:` character.
So I've checked these expressions in iex:

```
iex(16)> is_atom(List) 
true
iex(17)> is_atom(:List)
true
iex(18)> List == :List
false
iex(19)> a = List
List
iex(20)> b = :List
:List
```

So it's pretty clear that both `List` and `:List` are atoms. However, how does it work on Erlang interop layer? Because Erlang's `ok` is equal to Elixir's `:ok`.
So which one of these two (`List` and `:List`) is equal to `'List'` in Erlang?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Interactive Elixir (1.0.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> List == :List
false
iex(2)> List == :'Elixir.List'
true
```

All uppercase atoms in Elixir automatically receive the `Elixir.` prefix.

Comment: Great answer! To be 100% precise in the naming, `List`, `String` in Elixir are called aliases and they expand to atoms. So `List` expands to the :"Elixir.List". However, you can make an alias point to whatever you want using the `alias` special form, for example: `alias :foo, as: List`.

Comment: @JoséValim How can I achieve such alias from string than?
`String.to_atom("List")` gives `:List`.
I use `{atom, _} = Code.eval_string("List")` But I imagine it's not the safest way to do  it

Comment: Check `Module.concat/2` and `Module.split/1`.