# when calling function in which condition to add ":" before module name?

Tags: elixir

```
iex(5)>  IO.puts("hello world")
hello world
:ok
iex(6)> :math.exp(3)
20.085536923187668
```

When calling `IO.puts`, no need ":" before `IO`.

when calling `:math`, need ":" before math.

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Elixir's module an atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674102/is-elixirs-module-an-atom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Module names must be atoms.**

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), the literal starting with a capital letter is an atom. All domestic [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) modules are named starting with a capital letter.

[erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) modules are starting with a small letter, `:math` is an atom, `math` is not, in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). In [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang), `math` is already an atom.

Comment: "the literal starting with a capital letter is an atom" - more accurately, it's assumed to be a module name and is *converted* to an atom that is prefixed with `Elixir.`.

Comment: TIL, they're actually aliases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674102/is-elixirs-module-an-atom#comment47501637_29674200

Answer (score 1):

The colon is used to call an erlang function.  So, if you see a function in the erlang docs that you would like to call, then you have to precede the name with a colon.  Functions provided by Elixir are not preceded by a colon.

Comment: This has nothing to do with _functions_.